# How to safe restart explorer.exe with a batch file

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, batch, batch-file

I had a batch file, that restart my explorer.exe, when it lags, or when I need.

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
exit /b 0
```

But, sometimes it causes a problem - it reset my icons position on desktop. And it's really annoying.

Are there any ways to restart explorer safely to prevent that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your script and it works fine.
I have my icons move aswell when explorer reset
[image]
[image]
But what i noticed is if you move your icons to the place you want them to be then right click your desktop and click refresh then run your script it wont move the icons anymore.

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: It really works. But what I notice is, when many programs is running on my pc, it reset all my icons placing to left border. Without any load - even with 15 restarts in a row, it didn't reset icons